# Android boot loop on system img modification

Tags: android, bash

I'm trying to add some simple stuff to `app_process` by introducing a bash script before its invocation as follows:

**app_process**:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
ENV=env_data /system/bin/app_process.orig $*
```

However, after pushing the required files in via **adb**:

```
adb push app_process system/bin
adb push app_process.orig system/bin
```

The emulator won't start properly again with shell stop/start or running the emulator command with the modified system.img. It goes into some boot failure loop with the following error:

```
E/BandwidthController( 4244): runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -i lo --jump RETURN res=768
E/BandwidthController( 4244): runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -i lo --jump RETURN res=768
E/Netd    ( 4244): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
E/Netd    ( 4244): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
D/MDnsDS  ( 4244): MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
D/MDnsDS  ( 4244): MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
D/MDnsDS  ( 4244): Going to poll with pollCount 1
```

Is the way I'm calling `app_process` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the init can't run the script without specified executable.

The app_process are launched by the init process by reading its script, /init.rc.

The default command of Android in init.rc:
`service zygote /system/bin/app_process -Xzygote /system/bin --zygote --start-system-server`

And you might need change it to:
`service zygote /system/bin/sh /system/bin/app_process -Xzygote /system/bin --zygote --start-system-server`
This will let init run the script by invoke shell.

However If you want to modify init.rc, you need repack the ramdisk.img & boot.img and flash it.